# How to divide numbers by 10 but doesnt take the reminder

Tags: java

What do I do if I want to divide only tens? for example I have 16 when I divide it to 10 it will only answer 1 if I do 23 it will give me 2, like what I want to do is like diving 20(example) and 10 and it is ignoring the 6 in 26.

Answer (score 0):

Integer values ignore decimal places in division:

```java
int num = 236;

int div = num / 10;
int remainder = num % 10;

System.out.println("div = " + div);
System.out.println("remainder = " + remainder);
```

You can however use `float` or `double` instead though to get those decimal placed and then optionally round the result back to an integer.

```java
double withDecimal = (double) num / 10.0;
int rounded = (int) Math.round(withDecimal);

System.out.println("withDecimal = " + withDecimal);
System.out.println("rounded = " + rounded);
```

Comment: in this case `round` method will not work since it return, for example, 80 for 79.60 which the question wants to get 79

Answer (score 0):

`Integer` division in Java truncates decimals (hence the name). In order to maintain the decimals you have to make at least one of the variables a `double` or `float` like so:

```java
double x = 16 / 10.0; //1.6
double y = 23 / 10.0; //2.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: get the reminder by using number % 10;

Step 2: substract the reminder from the original number and store the result in a variable

Step 3: now divide the new number by 10.

```
public static void main(String []args){
    int number = 33;
    int reminder = number % 10;
    number = number - reminder;
    System.out.println(number / 10);
}
```